# How to hide chapter numbers in TOC with Memoir while keeping numbers at the start of each chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

I am using `memoir` and trying to hide chapter numbering in the table of contents ONLY. I wish to keep it in the `\mainmatter`
right now I am using `\chapter[Chapter 1]{}`  to keep the "Chapter 1" text hidden at the start of each chapter but keep the -1- numbering.  And "Chapter 1" text is in the table of contents as well.

I would like to keep this as is, but hide the 1 2 3 4 in the table of contents.  Right now I have 
1 Chapter 1                     2
2 Chapter 2                     5
3 Chapter 3                     15
4 Chapter 4                     23
which is a bit redundant.  Therefore I would like to remove the chapter numbers at the very start of each line before the word "Chapter".  Other packages I am using are:

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nextpage}
```

I have heard that the package `etoc` might be able to do this, but so far I have been unable to get it to do what I want.  I either hide every chapter from the table of contents or it hides the numbers from both the TOC and the chapters themselves.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,openany,twoside,extrafontsizes,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
All characters in this publication are fictitious and any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently, the markdown force is not really strong in you, DarthNewton ;-) Please use backticks to mark code as such ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to 'gooble' the chapter number away with

```
\def\cftchapterpresnum #1\@cftasnum{}
```

In addition, I suggest to reduce the `chapter indent` to `0pt` as well as the `numwidth`.

```
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0pt}
```

Here's the file:

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,11pt,openany,twoside,extrafontsizes,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\def\cftchapterpresnum #1\@cftasnum{}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\chapter{Chapter 1}
All characters in this publication are fictitious and any resemblance to real persons, living or dead, is purely coincidental.\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful!  Just what I was looking for.  Knew I was missing something and there had to be a easier way.  One question: is there a reason you have `\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0pt}` in the example twice? I tested and it seemed to work fine with the first one above document class omitted from my document.

Comment: @DarthNewton: Oh, there was a mistake actually: The first `\cftsetindents` was just a short explanation, but I forgot to use normal text as a clear separation from the MWE.

Comment: Ahh ok.  No problem easy to do (I have certainly made my share).  Thanks!

Comment: @DarthNewton: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!